# UWP AcrylicBrush backwards compatibility with min version 14393 (Anniversary Update)

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp, backwards-compatibility

I am working on my UWP app. I set up:

- Target version: **16299**
- Min version: **14393**

I use some AcrylicBrushes. Because they require 16299 version, I have two files with brushes:

- Styles/Brushes.xaml *(below 16299 - only SolidColorBrushes)*
- Styles/Fall/Brushes.xaml *(16299 and above - SolidColorBrushes and AcrylicBrushes)*

and I use code below in App.xaml.cs

```cs
private void SetupStyles() {
    var prefix = PlatformApiService.IsAcrylicBrushAvailable ? "Fall/" : string.Empty;
    var brushUri = new Uri($"ms-appx:///Styles/{prefix}Brushes.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
    Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary { Source = brushUri });
}
```

Everything works fine when min version is **10586**, but with **14393** my app can't build because:

> Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AcrylicBrush' is defined under contract 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract' version '5.0.0.0', but the contract version for the targeted min version is '3.0.0.0'!
>
> Member 'BackgroundSource' on type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.IAcrylicBrush' is defined under contract 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract' version '5.0.0.0', but the contract version for the targeted min version is '3.0.0.0'!
>
> Member 'FallbackColor' on type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.IXamlCompositionBrushBase' is defined under contract 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract' version '4.0.0.0', but the contract version for the targeted min version is '3.0.0.0'!

I can't use [Conditional XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/conditional-xaml), becase it requires 15063 version. What should I do?

Comment: I pretty much doubt "everything works fine" when you set your minimum version to 10586. If some resource is available only for Fall Creators Update (UniversalApiContract 5.0.0.0), how changing min version from Aniversary Update (3.0.0.0) to November Update (2.0.0.0) fix the issue?

Comment: @AndréB because as I said, I use two different Brushes.xaml files. In app.xaml.cs if app is launching on older version, it add Brushes.xaml with SolidColorBrushes, otherwise the one with AcrylicBrushes (Fall/Brushes.xaml). When min version is set to November Update, VS2017 successfully complete build with only warning that AcrylicBrush is supported from Fall Creators Update. But when min version is set to Anniversary, instead of warnings, VS2017 breaks build with errors.

Comment: As the [Conditional XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/conditional-xaml) document, to create a version adaptive app with a Minimum Version less than build 15063, you must use [version adaptive code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/version-adaptive-code) not XAML. Can't it achieve your requirement ? Also be curious about the **Everything works fine when min version is 10586, but not with 14393**, could you provide a simple repro project to help us see it?

Answer (score 3):

You can make the assets SolidColorBrushes in the XAML and then override them to Acrylic brushes in the C#

```
if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AcrylicBrush"))
{
                    var brush= ((SolidColorBrush)App.Current.Resources["ExampleBrush"]).Color;
                    App.Current.Resources["ExampleBrush"] = new AcrylicBrush()
                    {
                        TintOpacity = ,
                        TintColor = brush,
                        FallbackColor = brush,
                        BackgroundSource = AcrylicBackgroundSource.HostBackdrop
                    };
}
```